# Why is $\sum^{n}_{i=1} \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} = \int_{a}^{b} $?

Tags: integration, plane-curves

This is a part of my proof:

> $$\begin{align}
> \left| \sum^{n}_{i=1} V(r(\tau_i)) \cdot  \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}  r'(t)  dt - \int_{a}^{b} V(r(t)) \cdot r'(t)  dt \right|
> &\leq 
> \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} \| V(r(\tau_i))-V(r(t)) \| \; \| r'(t) \| dt \\
> &\le
> \frac{\varepsilon}{l} \displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i=1} \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} \| r'(t) \| dt
> \\
> &\le 
> \frac{\varepsilon}{l} \int_{a}^{b} \| r'(t) \| dt \\
> &= \varepsilon 
> \end{align}$$

My only question is how $ \displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i=1} \displaystyle \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} $ $ = $  $ \displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} $ ?

Comment: Probably $a = t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < \dotsc < t_{n-1} < t_n = b$.

Comment: Thats right. I should know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a = t_0 \le t_1 \le t_2 \ldots \le t_n = b$ then by induction we can show
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{t_i-1}^{t_i} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x + \cdots + \int_{t_{n-1}}^{t_n} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_{t_0}^{t_n} f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
$$
at least for the Riemann integral.